# Spring configuration launch before each unit test for the same test class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, hsqldb

I try to integrate hsqldb (memory db) in my project, because from the beginning, all DAO are tested with a real database and its not very safe, because when database is not up, jenkins failed all test!

but i see something strange when i launch a test class.

I have three test in my class and when i doing run as junit test with eclipse, i see spring configuration reloaded before each unit test. Does it normal? because i have use

```
 <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">import.sql</prop>
```

and this file contain many create table, and when the second test is launch, i see error messages : "table toto already exist..."

does it possible to have spring configuration loaded only one for all test in the class?

here is my configuration :

```
    <bean name="dataSource"     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:castor;syntax.ora=true" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>


     <bean id="hibernateSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="mappingLocations" value="classpath*:fr/**/*.hbm.xml"/>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
     <prop key="hibernate.dialect">fr.edf.mpv2.castor.persistance.HsqlOracleDialect</prop>
     <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
     <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
     <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">import.sql</prop>
     <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
     <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
     <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>


      <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
     <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
     <property name="rollbackOnCommitFailure" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

its a legacy project, and people who start the project with spring doesn't know how its work, so they doesn't use injection :( and they create a factory that load the spring configuration instead of use applicationContext.xml...

so for help developper i have create a mock to override the factory in test context

here is the declaration :

```
   public class MailDAOTest extends BeanFactoryOverrider {
   ....



    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest({ BeanFactory.class })
    @PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
    public class BeanFactoryOverrider {

    /** Context spring de test. */
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
```

so everywhere in the code where we use the factory with is own springcontext, i override method to use my own spring context with my own configuration and not the real production configuration.
this work fine, but its just to explain why i m using PowerkMockRunner ;)

i use spring 2.0 / hibernate 3.2.6 / hsql 2.3.2

thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you specify context configuration location on your test class, and use spring test runner the context will be cached not reloaded each time.

Something like :

```
@RunWith (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration (locations = "classpath:/config/applicationContext-test.xml")
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyTest {}
```

Comment: yes but as i have say, i m forced to use @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) can i combine both of them? if not i can't use SpringJunit4ClassRunner :( and its seem to be not available in spring 2.0...

Comment: can tou explain a little more what you suggest please? i m not sure to understand, thanks

Comment: my comment didn't amke sense, more caffiene - if you can;t migrate to spring - sorry I can;t help